# Broadcast or Publish/Subscribe to update thousands of users

Tags: c#, architecture, client-server

I have a client/server application that needs to keep each user's application up to date with a set of status information.

Typically there will be up to 1,000 concurrent users, but this may expand to 5,000 or beyond in the future.

Updates need to be provided approximately every 10 seconds so that user's view of the application is never out of date.

Which would be the best approach (this is a .Net C#) application?

- A 'Broadcast' mechanism where each client 'listens' for an update message
- A Publish/Subscribe mechanism where each connected client tellse the server to send it a message every 10 seconds
- Client Request - every 10 seconds, each client requests the current data

The system I have inherited uses the last approach - and does not scale to the extent needed.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say a client request, because I'd expect that to be the simplest solution... but WHY, in your experience, doesn't it "scale" well? I suspect that there simply isn't enough network capacity to handle that many request/responses.

Comment: if you are architecting a system that will handle 5000 concurrent users, shouldn't you already have a btter idea of how to design it?

Comment: I would suggest a heartbeat that the server sends out via Multicast. This heartbeat will contain all of the information that is needed to be sent to the clients and the clients only listen in for any incoming packets. The heartbeat can be controlled by a timer on the server and sent out whenever the timers elapsed event is fired.

Comment: I highly recommend asynchronous IO and event loops for this. 1 Process/thread per concurrent user does not scale. To avoid having 1000 connections open at the same time the best alternative is client request. (Something like node.js will trivially scale to 5000 concurrent users on one server due to asynchronous IO and event loops)

Comment: Regarding the broadcast option - are the clients all on a LAN?  Or do you mean something other than UDP Broadcasts (i.e. clients subscribe and the server enumerates known subscriptions to broadcast changes?).  If the latter, I would recommend that option.  It seems to use the least number of connections/bandwidth because the server only transmits on status updates and only receives when there is a (re)new client/sub'.  I'd have the clients resubscribe at set intervals because you can't rely on the clients disconnecting/unsubscribing. I'm also assuming status updates slower than every 10 secs?

Comment: Also, definitely look to use [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) with appropriate SAEA, Memory, and general resouce pooling.  A good example to work from can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an architecture that implements something along the lines of NodeJS, or in the .NET arena, something like SignalR (there are others popping out, take a look at the project here

https://github.com/SignalR

and the demo

http://chatapp.apphb.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

That way - only clients that are interested would listen and publisher wouldn't be "DDoS`ed".

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on just approach, I recommend multicast. On startup client must register himself for a multicast group and then server sends packet to that multicast group. By this way you can reduce overhead due to broadcasting. Secondly, you may seriously think about threading in your scenario. Handling thousand clients with a single thread can't be a wise solution

You can refer this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/multicast.aspx) of Code Project as an example for multicasting

Comment: Though this method does introduce a hardware requirement for the OP's clients in that all routers must be capable of multicast.

Comment: "Handling thousand clients with a single thread can't be a wise solution." Why not? A thread pool is probably optimal, but single thread is perfectly acceptable, especially compared to the horror of a separate thread per client.